# Change default Service Unavailable message when REST api call fails

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, rest, tomcat

When user tries to do api call but if our server is down (due to many reasons) then my website UI gives following error:

> Service Unavailable
>
> The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to
>   maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
>   Additionally, a 406 Not Acceptable error was encountered while trying
>   to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.6 Server at localhost Port 80

I don't want this message to be this much detailed. I want to customize this message. How can I do this? Better if you suggest something **change on my ajax request** (from where I do api calls)

Here is the javascript from where I do all my api request (if it helps)

```
function request(url, request_type, datatype, callback, postdata){

        if(typeof(postdata) == "object"){
            postdata = JSON.stringify(postdata);
        } else if(typeof(postdata) == "string") {
            SY.setContentType("text/plain");
        }

        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function(xhr){
                for(var key in requestHeaders){
                    if(key == ANOTHER_CONTENT_TYPE)
                        continue;

                    xhr.setRequestHeader(key, requestHeaders[key]);    
                }

                var client_id = readCookie(CLIENT_ID);
                var client_token = readCookie(CLIENT_TOKEN);
                if(client_id != null && client_token != null){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(CLIENT_ID, client_id);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader(CLIENT_TOKEN, client_token);
                }

                //if there is another content type defined then modify the xhr content-type header
                var newContentType = requestHeaders[ANOTHER_CONTENT_TYPE];
                if(newContentType != undefined) {
                    SyUtils.log("Changing request content type to ="+newContentType);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", newContentType);
                    delete requestHeaders[ANOTHER_CONTENT_TYPE];
                }

                var loadingDivId = callback.loadingDivId;
                if(loadingDivId){
                    $("#"+loadingDivId).addClass("loader-small");
                }else{
                    $("body").append("<div id=\"loader\"></div>");
                }

            },
            url: url,
            data: postdata,
            dataType: datatype,
            type: request_type,
            success: function(data) {

                var loadingDivId = callback.loadingDivId;
                if(loadingDivId){
                    $("#"+loadingDivId).removeClass("loader-small");
                }else{
                    $("#loader").remove();
                }

                // Write back cookie again so that expiry time refreshes
                var client_id = readCookie(CLIENT_ID);
                var client_token = readCookie(CLIENT_TOKEN);
                if(client_id != null && client_token != null){
                    saveCredentials(client_id, client_token);
                }
                callback("success", data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                var loadingDivId = callback.loadingDivId;
                if(loadingDivId){
                    $("#"+loadingDivId).removeClass("loader-small");
                }else{
                    $("#loader").remove();
                }
                try{
                    var errorMessageObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                }catch(err){
                    errorMessageObj = {type:"ERROR", message:xhr.responseText};
                }

                var st = xhr.status;
                var currentPage = window.location.pathname; // to avoid infinite redirect loop
                if (st == 401 && currentPage != "/login"){
                    SY.removeCurrentUser();
                    deleteCookie(CLIENT_ID);
                    deleteCookie(CLIENT_TOKEN);
                    window.location.replace("/login?toPage="+currentPage);
                }else if(st == 403 && currentPage != "/unauthorized"){
                    window.location.replace("/unauthorized");
                }else if(st == 500 && currentPage != "/error"){
                    window.location.href = "/error";
                }else if(st == 404 && currentPage != "/404"){
                    window.location.href = "/404";
                }else{
                    callback(error, errorMessageObj);
                }   
            }
        });
    };
```